# JS Recursively find element in parent-child array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

i have a array with a nested parent-child structure. I need to recursively go through this array and find wanted element. 
I wrote this function:

```
recursivelyFindElementByCondition(nodes, isSatisfyingCondition) {

    function recursiveCheck(items) {
        for (const item of items) {
            if (isSatisfyingCondition(item)) {
                return item;
            }

            if (item.rows) {
                recursiveCheck(item.rows)
            }
        }
    }

    return recursiveCheck(nodes);
}
```

But i don't understand why it returns undefined. It should work correct as far as i understand.
I know that there is a way to create a variable out of scope of recursive function and assign element to it and then return it in the end, just wanted to do it without unnecessary variable and have no idea why is approach above doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing your `return` before the `recursiveCheck(item.rows)` call

Comment: You're also missing a return in the case that both ifs are false, for all items.

Comment: If you show your input structure and expected result, it'd be a lot easier to provide you with a working solution. As others have said, though, this doesn't work because your `return item` is not being correctly passed back up the call stack. Every branch through the code needs to return the result if it's found--the recursion works like a chain, not an immediate return to the original calling scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of the recursive call must be returned, for it to propagate up to the point of invocation and be returned as the result.

```js
function findNode(nodes, predicate) {
    for (const node of nodes) {
        if (predicate(node)) return node

        if (node.rows) {
            let match = findNode(node.rows, predicate)
            if (match) return match
        }
    }
}

const tree = [{
    value: 'a',
    rows: [{
        value: 'b'
    }]
}, {
    value: 'c',
    rows: [{
        value: 'd',
        rows: [{
            value: 'e'
        }]
    }]
}]

const result = findNode(tree, ({value}) => value === 'e')

console.log(result)
```